# File name with vbs scripts

Tags: vbscript

I want to add a charecter file name. 
For Example

```
123456.jpg --> 1234506.jpg 
ABCDEF.jpg --> ABCDE0F.jpg
```

orginal file `6 charecters` new file name `7 charecter` (I want to add 0 for all file name Please attention after 0 character has a character.)

for this proccess`batch file or vbs`

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "delims=" %%a in (
        'dir /b /a-d ^| 
            findstr /r /b 
            /c:"[^.][^.][^.][^.][^.][^.]\."
            /c:"[^.][^.][^.][^.][^.][^.]$" 
        '
    ) do (
        set "fileName=%%a"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        for %%b in ("!filename:~0,5!0!filename:~5!") do endlocal & if not exist "%%~b" echo ren "%%a" "%%~b"
    )
```

This uses `dir` command to retrieve the list of files and `findstr` to filter and only get the files with 6 characters in filename. For each file found, the file name is retrieved into a variable, and substring operation is done to compose the new name.

To avoid problems with exclamations in file names, we need to have delayed expansion enabled to read the variable, but disabled to execute the command. This is the reason for the second `for`, enable delayed expansion, read the required value and store it inside the `for` command replaceable parameter, disable delayed expansion and now, without problem with exclamations, execute the required command.

The `ren` command is only echoed to console. If the output is correct, remove the `echo` to execute the rename operation

Answer (score 0):

Here's how it can be done with VBScript and a `FileSystemObject`. This script will need to be in the same folder as your files. Otherwise, you'll have to use the full path to your files.

```
' Files to update...
a = Array("123456.jpg", "ABCDEF.jpg")

With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    For i = 0 To UBound(a)

        ' Change name. Use first 5 chars, plus "0", plus rest...
        .GetFile(a(i)).Name = Left(a(i), 5) & "0" & Mid(a(i), 6)

    Next
End With
```